# Removing file lines containing data which are not present in another file

Tags: java, performance, algorithm, unix

I have a file Hier.csv which looks like this (thousands of lines):

```
value;nettingNodeData;ADM59505_10851487;CVAEngine;ADM;;USD;0.4;35661;BDR;NA;ICE;;RDC;MAS35661_10851487;CVAEngine;MA;10851487;RDC
```

I have another one, Prices.csv, which looks like this :

```
value;nettingNodePrices;ADM68834_22035364;CVAEngine;CVA with FTD;EUR;1468.91334249291905;DVA with FTD;EUR;5365.59742483701497
```

I have to make sure that both files have the same number of lines and the same ids (the third value of each lines), and it's a known fact that the set of ids from Hier.csv is larger and contains the set of ids from Prices.csv, ie. some ids that are in Hier.csv are not in Prices.csv.
Also, there are no duplicates in either file.

So far, I have tried the following, but it's taking ages, and not working (I can do it faster with my little hands and Excel, but that's not what I want).

Here is my program in pseudo code, as I don't have access to my code right now, I will edit this question as soon as I can :

```
for each line of Hier.csv
    for each line of Prices.csv
        if prices.line doesn't contain the 3rd value of hier.line
            store that value in a list
        end
    end
end

Process p;
for each value in the list
    // remove the line containing that value from Hier.csv
    String[] command1 = {"sed", "'/^.*" + value + ".*$/d'", "Hier.csv", ">", "tmp.csv"};
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command1)
end
String[] command2 = {"mv", "tmp.csv" "Hier.csv"};
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command2)
```

Is there a better way than that double loop ?
Why does'nt the last part (exec(command)) work ?
And lastly, which is more efficient when reading csv files : BufferedReader or Scanner ?

Comment: Load both files into memory, sort both lists by the third value, then check for missing values.

Answer (score 1):

You can use merge or hashtable.
Merge:
sort both files and merge together
Hashtable:
load smaller file (ids) to hashtable, loop through bigger file and test existence against hashtable

Comment: As an algorithm it's fine, just don't use `java.util.HashMap` as it's old crap (use `HashMap` instead).